# Doveadm command for delete all emails on user filtered by subject

Tags: dovecot

I have a problem and I can't solve it with doveadm

I have an email that by mistake has more than 500,000 emails in the INBOX with a unique subject that is easy to isolate.
**blocked**

With

```
doveadm search -u box@mydomain.com SUBJECT blocked
f8ef401d6ad78f623d4b0000ea3e7c6d 101
f8ef401d6ad78f623d4b0000ea3e7c6d 104
f8ef401d6ad78f623d4b0000ea3e7c6d 108
. . .
```

I get, (I think), the list of messages that this subject has

I tried another approach but it doesn't work

```
doveadm -v expunge -u box@mydomain.commailbox INBOX SUBJECT blocked
```

As much as I read and reread the doveadm manual, I can't reach the happy ending.

Edited: Not work is this:

- After running the command, emails with the subject are NOT deleted.
- Id run a `doveadm search -u abdelkarim.xxxx@my.comain SUBJECT blocked`  I get the same list of emails with this subject.

Comment: Please [add the specific](https://serverfault.com/posts/1127198/edit) problem / error printed / logged instead of "doesn't work"

Comment: @anx edited. Is correct now?

Comment: Wait, is that typo (missing space after -u argument) the actual command you used?

Comment: try `doveadm fetch -f tab -u user@example.org 'mailbox hdr.subject hdr.date' SUBJECT blocked` to verify what you are searching is indeed stored in INBOX

Comment: `fetch: invalid option -- 'f' ` and not missing space `after -u argument` @anx

Comment: sorry, I gave you the wrong option order. the point was to use the fetch (in pace of search) command to have your search print additional columns, such as the mailbox of each search result.